# HSA Employer Excess Contribution: W2 vs Other Income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, health-insurance, hsa, excess-contribution

**Form 8889** instructions state that **excess employer contributions** should be included in income on **Form W-2**. (**Box 1** I assume?) If this is not done, instructions state that excess employer contributions must be reported as **Other Income**.

To me it looks like the first method (reporting the excess employer contribution on **Form W-2**) results in payment of **FICA taxes**, and the second method (reporting the excess employer contributions as **Other Income**) doesn't result in payment of **FICA taxes**.

This looks a bit weird. Is the assumption above correct? In my particular situation, the employer doesn't want/know to assist me in correcting the excess contribution so my only option is to report it as **Other Income**. However, I want to make sure that by doing so I do not omit something, for example, the payment of **FICA** taxes if that's required.

Here is the quote from **Form 8889** instructions:

> **Excess Employer Contributions:**
>   Excess employer contributions are the
>   excess, if any, of your employer's
>   contributions over your limitation on
>   line 8. (...) **If the excess was not
>   included in income on Form W-2, you
>   must report it as “Other income” on your
>   tax return.** However, you can withdraw
>   some or all of the excess employer
>   contributions for 2015 and they will be
>   treated as if they had not been
>   contributed if (...)

Answer (score 2):

The instructions for IRS Form 8889 Line #13 [Form 8889, Health Savings Accounts (HSAs)](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8889/index.html) indicate that you should report the excess contributions as other income and that you should also report on IRS Form 5329 Line #47 [Form 5329, Additional Taxes on Qualified Plans (Including IRAs) and Other Tax-Favored Accounts](https://www.irs.gov/uac/about-form-8889) which is where the Social Security and Medicare tax will be figured and then entered on IRS Form 1040 Line #59.

> Line 13
>
> If you or someone on your behalf (or your employer) contributed more
> to your HSA than is allowable, you may have to pay an additional tax
> on the excess contributions. Figure the excess contributions using the
> following instructions. See Form 5329, Additional Taxes on Qualified
> Plans (Including IRAs) and Other Tax-Favored Accounts, to figure the
> additional tax.

In short - you'll be taxed either way, but one way is a bit more complicated to figure.

Comment: My understanding is that Form 5329 is required only when the excess contributions are not withdrawn by return due date. Also, I don't see any mention of FICA (social security and Medicare) taxes on Form 5329, nor any way to determine/pay these taxes (especially the employer's part of these taxes). As far as I understand Form 5329 is used only to pay annual 6% excise tax on non-withdrawn excess contributions.